# `user` name as alias for table does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, alias

So I have this simple query written in Postgres:

```sql
SELECT cp.contest_id, cp.username, user.rating FROM contest_participants cp 
  JOIN users user ON user.username = cp.username WHERE contest_id = '?';
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: SELECT cp.contest_id, cp.username, user.rating FROM contest_...
```

If I change the `user` table alias name, it's working like a charm but is bothering me not to know why exactly is that. Is there a problem with the alias name or it can be something else with the entire schema structure from the database?

As far as I can tell, the query is isolated to the selection I made, right?

Comment: Use double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"user"`.

Comment: There is already a hint in the syntax coloring here: "user" is keyword-blue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres SQL, `user` is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias or other database object name, [see the documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

For an immediate fix, you may escape the alias in double quotes:

```sql
SELECT cp.contest_id, cp.username, user.rating
FROM contest_participants cp 
JOIN users "user" ON "user".username = cp.username
WHERE contest_id = '?';
```

Or, you could just an alias like `usr`, which gets across the same meaning without requiring escaping.